# Nautilus crashes when dragging files in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, gnome, nautilus

I'm running Gnome in Ubuntu 10.04. Nautilus used to work fine on my system but now it's doing something strange. Whenever I drag a file out of the Nautilus window to move it somewhere else, as soon as the mouse cursor goes out of the window Nautilus closes and the file I was dragging also disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed some Nautilus extensions or other software lately?

Comment: Should be a comment, imo.